# KVM linux bridge

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, bridge, kvm-switch

I'm quite new in networking. I have an server with an ip addr a on eth0. Now I have via KVM an VM running on the server. I've got an other ip addr b which I want to use for the vm so that it will be connected to the Inet. I've created a bridge br0 (I've added a route and activate ipv4 forward):

```
iface br0 inet manual
    pre-up brctl addbr br0
    address 178.*.*.*
    gateway 178.*.*.*
    netmask 255.255.255.192
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_ports none
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

In the vm I can't get networking work. I hope I'll get some help.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to tell the VM to use the bridge Interface rather then the default virtbr interface.

You can do this in virtmanager by opening the VM, clicking the "i" button, clicking on "NIC xxxxx", and, if it appears in the dropdown box selecting the br0 interface - if not you will need to specify shared device name as "br0"